# Change dictionary values in specific order with function/class

Tags: python, class, dictionary

Hey so I am a beginner at Python and I hope to get some help by a pro with my code.

I am making a seemingly really easy game but I've come across some challenges regarding functions.
I have a 3x3 table (like tic-tac-toe) but instead of two we play it with three characters.
I like Foxes so the three characters are F - O - X.

```
-----------
|x |o |x |
|--|--|--|
|f |f |o |
|o |f |o |
------------
```

The game mechanic is also easy in theory. You pick a place to change and everything near that tile and the tile itself changes, so let's say you change the first x at the top here.

```
-----------
|x |o |x |
|--|--|--|
|f |f |o |
|o |f |o |
------------
```

You would get this. Every X turns into a O and then it turns to a F and then back to X.
It only changes everything next to it and doesn't change it diagonally.

I store these in a dictionary. (At the end it's only an illustration I made a function to randomly generate either F or O or X into every key as a value but I wanted to keep this as short as possible.)

My problem is how can I create a function that's not 200 lines long to change the values of either three or four specific key's value easily?
I included the essential codes down below.

```
class CheckValue:

    #We get a value randomly
    def varom(self):
        pos_value = ['f','o','x']
        out_value = random.choice(pos_value)
        return out_value

    #We try to change the value of a key not manually but by changing everything in a dictionary
    def checkself(self):
        if self == 'f':
            self = 'o'
        elif self == 'o':
            self = 'x'
        else:
            self = 'f'
#I assign every key to the CheckValue class to try to handle them objects
a = CheckValue()
b = CheckValue()
c = CheckValue()
d = CheckValue()
e = CheckValue()
f = CheckValue()
g = CheckValue()
h = CheckValue()
i = CheckValue()

theBoard = {'0': a.varom() , '1': b.varom(), '2': c.varom(),
            '3': d.varom(), '4': e.varom(), '5': f.varom(),
            '6': g.varom(), '7': h.varom(), '8': i.varom()}

def printBoard(board):
    print('|' + board['0'] + ' ' + '|' + board['1'] + ' ' + '|' + board['2'] + ' ' + '|')
    print('|' + board['3'] + ' ' + '|' + board['4'] + ' ' + '|' + board['5'] + ' ' + '|')
    print('|' + board['6'] + ' ' + '|' + board['7'] + ' ' + '|' + board['8'] + ' ' + '|')

def maingame():
    printBoard(theBoard)
    print('Here is your gameboard! Try to do the fox!')
    print('The game is simple! ')
    print('Choose a given number and everything next to it will shift to another letter')
    print('If you select "F" it will torn to a "O", "O" will turn to "X" and "X" will turn to "F"')
    print('If you get "F-O-X" in a row or column you won')

    while True:
        player_choice = int(input("Pick an number from 0 to 8:"))
        if player_choice in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8):
            if player_choice == 0:
                a.checkself()
                b.checkself()
                c.checkself()
                printBoard(theBoard)
            # I would use if statements from 0-1 to modify everything by hand but that would be long so I just did this to show an example.
        else:
            print("Please try again")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    maingame()
```

Comment: OK, for starters, `if self == 'f'` etc doesn't make any sense. `self` will be an instance of your `CheckValue` class, so it will *never equal any string* (unless you implemented it to work that way, which you haven't, and you probably shouldn;'t)

Comment: Thanks omg! You got any ideas to this? I first tried this without making a class because I don't fully get them right now, but that's a longer process.